# iOS - Accessibility methods - moving focus

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I am working on an app and trying to make it as accessible as possible. I am trying to move focus to a certain element once an action takes place. I was curious about the difference between these two functions:

UIAccessibilityFocusedElement vs. UIAccessibilityPostNotification

If someone could explain the difference between the two it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't directly address the difference between the two, but an amazing overview I have starred that might solve your problem and directly relates to `UIAccessibilityPostNotification`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797515/actual-difference-between-uiaccessibilitylayoutchangednotification-and-uiaccessi

Comment: sorry for the late response. yeah didn't really answer the question but did help with my problem.

Answer (score 4):

UIAccessibilityPostNotification is used to change things (like focused elements but also pausing and resuming assistive technology like that:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .pauseAssistiveTechnology, argument: UIAccessibility.AssistiveTechnologyIdentifier.notificationSwitchControl)
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .resumeAssistiveTechnology, argument: UIAccessibility.AssistiveTechnologyIdentifier.notificationSwitchControl)
```

It can also announce something:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: "Say something")
```

or refresh focus after accessibility scroll

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .pageScrolled, argument: nil)
```

On the other hand `UIAccessibilityFocusedElement` can't change anything. It just returns currently focused element (or `nil`) this way:

```
UIAccessibility.focusedElement(using: UIAccessibility.AssistiveTechnologyIdentifier.notificationVoiceOver)
```

On a side note - for now only assistive technology that can be paused or resumed is notificationSwitchControl, trying that with Voice Over causes crashes

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to move focus to an element based off an actions / screen change scenario.

I think you should probably take a look at:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, element_to_be_focused>);
```

*Should be posted when a new view appears that encompasses a major portion of the screen.*

or

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, element_to_be_focused);
```

*Should be posted when the layout of a screen changes, for example when an individual element appears or disappears.*